# How to check if the root filesystem has been mounted in linux

Tags: linux, file, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I was wondering if it was possible to know if the rootfile system has been mounted from the kernel. Im trying to read a file from /bin but it doesnt work on boot.

`static int ret_my_file()` is in `fs/exec.c`

```
static int ret_my_file()  
{
struct file* f;

char *dbtext;
struct path dbpath;

mm_segment_t oldfs;
struct kstat dbstat;

kern_path("/bin/myfile", 0, &dbpath);
vfs_getattr(&dbpath, &dbstat);

dbtext = vmalloc(dbstat.size*sizeof(char));
f=filp_open("/bin/myfile", O_RDONLY, 0);

oldfs=get_fs();
set_fs (KERNEL_DS);
vfs_read(f, dbtext, dbstat.size, &f->f_pos);
set_fs(oldfs);
printk(KERN_CRIT "Db value is");
printk(KERN_CRIT "%s\n",dbtext);
vfree(dbtext);
return 0;
}
```

called in the function  `do_execveat_common()`  also in  `fs/exec.c`  as

```
static int do_execveat_common(int fd, struct filename *filename,
                           struct user_arg_ptr argv,
                           struct user_arg_ptr envp,
                          int flags)
{
 char *pathbuf = NULL;
 struct linux_binprm *bprm;
 struct file *file;
 struct files_struct *displaced;
 int retval;

 retval=ret_my_file();
 ......}
```

but the function  `do_execveat_common()`  is called during boot up so i wanted to put a condition before  `retval=ret_my_file();`  so that it only runs after the root filesystem has been mounted

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Very similar but deleted question (for 10k users): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713849/what-is-the-necessary-path-of-the-filp-open-in-linux. It also contains oops trace.

Comment: I am unsure whether `execve*` **syscall** can be called without root filesystem mounted. As a dirty workaround, you may skip first call to this function by using static counter: `static int counter = 0; if(++counter > 1) ret_my_file();`

Comment: yup that did it,thanks! but is there no way to check for the mounting of filesystem?